# Number of 4 digit numbers having its digits in descending order

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The title says it all . So I will directly start with my attempt. $$\text {Attempt} $$. Lets start with $987X $ where x is a digit. So $X $ can be from $0-6=7$ ways.  Now lets do for $986X $ ...$6$ ways ,then $5,4,3,2,1$ ways accordingly. Then for $976X,975X... $..... so again $6,5,4,3,2,1$ ways. This counting is taking more time . I also tried for $0-10,0-100,0-1000$ and then get some relation for general n but i failed. Thus I want some shortcut trick to solve it quickly and logically.

Comment: Number of combinations $10\choose 4$ gives the number of 4-elemen subset of the set $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. Thing is, a set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with four elements corresponds to a chain $a>b>c>d$. The elements in a set are unordered but can be ordered that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just choose any four numbers from $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ and arrange them in descending order.

Number of integers is $\binom{10}{4}=210$.

Comment: Oh i am embarrased couldnt think of this. But thanks:)